# What guidelines are appropriate for determining when to implement a class member as a property versus a method?

Tags: c#, .net

The [.NET coding standards PDF from SubMain](http://submain.com/landing/codeit.right/?utm_campaign=codeit.right&utm_medium=textad&utm_source=stackoverflow) that have started showing up in the "Sponsored By" area seems to indicate that properties are only appropriate for logical data members (see pages 34-35 of the document).  Methods are deemed appropriate in the following cases:

- The operation is a conversion, such as Object.ToString().

  The operation is expensive enough that you want to communicate to the user that they should consider caching the result.

  Obtaining a property value using the get accessor would have an observable side effect.

  Calling the member twice in succession produces different results.

  The order of execution is important.

  The member is static but returns a value that can be changed.

  The member returns an array.

Do most developers agree on the properties vs. methods argument above?  If so, why?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They seem sound, and basically in line with MSDN member design guidelines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229059.aspx

One point that people sometimes seem to forget (*) is that callers should be able to set properties in any order.  Particularly important for classes that support designers, as you can't be sure of the order generated code will set properties.

(*) I remember early versions of the Ajax Control Toolkit on Codeplex had numerous bugs due to developers forgetting this one.

As for "Calling the member twice in succession produces different results", every rule has an exception, as the property DateTime.Now illustrates.

Comment: DateTime.Now may be a literal exception, but logically it returns the same thing every call.

Answer (score 1):

Those are interesting guidelines, and I agree with them.  It's interesting in that they are setting the rules based on "everything is a property except the following".  That said, they are good guidelines for avoiding problems by defining something as a property that can cause issues later.

At the end of the day a property is just a structured method, so the rule of thumb I use is based on Object Orientation -- if the member represents data owned by the entity, it should be defined as a property; if it represents behavior of the entity it should be implemented as a method.

Answer (score 0):

Fully agreed.

According to the coding guidelines properties are "nouns" and methods are "verbs". Keep in mind that a user may call the property very often while thinking it would be a "cheap" operation.

On the other side it's usually expected that a method may "take more time", so a user considers about caching method results.

Answer (score 0):

What's so interesting about those guidelines is that they are clearly an argument for having extension properties as well as extension methods. Shame.

Comment: How is this an argument for extension properties?

Comment: @ScottDorman: Essentially because there are situations where an extension member would more logically be a property than a method.  For example, if one often wants the center X coordinate of a `Rectangle`, one could define an extension method `CenterX()`, but an extension property `CenterX` would seem more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I never personally came to the conclusion or had the gut feeling that properties are fast, but the guidelines say they should be, so I just accept it.

I always struggle with what to name my slow "get" methods while avoiding FxCop warnings.  GetPeopleList() sounds good to me, but then FxCop tells me it might be better as a property.

Comment: FxCop generates a lot of false positives.  In a case like that, you're right to exclude the violation.

Comment: Generate/Build/RetrievePeopleList?