# Implement validation as a method or as a property?

Tags: c#

I have an object that needs a test if the object data is valid. The validation itself would be called from the thread that instatiated the object, it looks like this:

```
 {
  if (_step.Equals(string.Empty)) return false;
  if (_type.Equals(string.Empty)) return false;
  if (_setup.Equals(string.Empty)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Would it be better to implement this as a property, or as a method, and why? I have read the answers to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164023/what-guidelines-are-appropriate-for-determining-when-to-implement-a-class-membe), but I don't think this specific question is covered there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal opinion here would be:

- If the "validate" method mutates the object in any way (which your example doesn't) then make it a method.
- If the object remains un-changed after validation, make it a property.

Answer (score 1):

I would say as a Property.

```
if(something.IsValid) { ...
```

looks better then

```
if(something.IsValid()) { ...
```

Also an example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That code needs refactoring. This is how you write code in Java, not in C#. In C#, you've got operator overloading.

```
if (_step == "")) return false;
if (_type == "")) return false;
if (_setup == "")) return false;
```

This is the idiomatic way of doing the comparison. Your way, besides being more verbose, is just unexpected and inconsistent in C#.

If, *and only if*, there's a chance that these strings are actually `null` instead of empty, use the following instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_step)) return false;
```

Comment: I remember reading somwhere that it is recommended to use Equals(...) in C# as well, because of some CLR specific stuff. Of course I don't remember *where* I read this...

Comment: Yeah, there are several articles on the web claiming such nonsense (searching for "effective C#" turns up several, besides the good book of the same title). However, they have repeatedly been debunked.

Comment: I would create an bool AreNulls(params object[] parameters); method to handle those cases if it is very common.

Comment: That's all well and good, but - it doesn't answer the original question. That said, using string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToCheck) or stringToCheck == string.Empty are definetly the way to go.

Comment: Rob, The original question has already been answered and I personally have nothing to add to your answer.

Comment: Didn't Jon Skeet say that string.length == 0 was a more efficient way to check for empty strings ...?

Comment: @5arx I don’t know every single think that Jon Skeet said but first of all, the gain in speed would be marginal at best, given that `==` for strings internally checks for length. And secondly, I still think that `== ""` is more readable and therefore preferred.

Comment: Ha ha I was invoking the spectre of @JonSkeet as a shorthand for 'isn't the recommended way ...?' ;-)

I was thinking specifically of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279(v=vs.100).aspx   
  

> "When targeting .NET Framework 2.0, use the IsNullOrEmpty method. Otherwise, use the Length == comparison whenever possible.

Comment: @5arx Thanks for the link. What a brain-dead warning/rule. If the framework producers are aware of the issue, why don’t they fix it? This should definitely be feasible. `Object.Equals` should simply **never** be invoked when comparing two strings, there is no sense in that, and if it does, this is a bug in the framework.